# Security of Solid Explorer Hash

Tags: applications, google-play-store, security, files

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask, but how secure is checking file hash with Solid Explorer for Android?
I don't have computer access so it's my only option.
Does anyone know if it's a bad idea like if it collects file data that way or uploads it to a database, or does it literally just calculate the hash and nothing more so it's safe to use?
I've never done it before so I'm lost.
This is for my files not to compare files.

Actually are Google play store hash apps safe at all?
I'm aware sites are not as they can be collected into a data base and out in the open, but are the appstore apps secure?

Comment: PlayStore is not Fort Nox. Google tries to prevent the worst but they can't guarantee security of any app. If you just want to generate the hash of a file a smaller simpler app is usually better as it is harder to hide something in a smaller app. Anyway if you just want to calculate some file hashes I recommend to use an app from F-Droid store, e.g. [Hash Droid](https://f-droid.org/de/packages/com.hobbyone.HashDroid/). All apps in this store are open source directly built from source by the store itself.

Comment: I understand, thank you, but now my bigger question is does hashing a file upload it's contents at all when it has to calculate?

Comment: Sorry but the question in your last comment is formulated in a way that I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: Sorry, when you calculate the hash of a file, does it expose the actual file contents to the program/application? I'm asking because the file contents determine the hash number, correct? Does it read the file contents?

Comment: Computers don't use magic, hence if you want to compute the hash of a file the file must be read from the first to the last byte. There is no other way to calculate a hash. Therefore Hash Droid app is perfect because it is very simple and has no permission at all, no internet, bluetooth, or whatever connection can't be opened by this app.

Comment: If you're okay with Linux command line, you could use Termux. You could check checksums for wg, to check md5sum, you could use `md5sum nameofapp.apk`. There's also sha256sum, sha512sum and more if you want to check that out as well.